# Drunkness on Purim and Alcoholism

Tags: purim, psych-mentalhealth, liquor-beer, intoxication, drinking

Are there any poskim that formally address alcoholism and Purim? Is there a formal pesak halakha saying if one is an alcoholic, they are not to get drunk.

Comment: There are loads of sources that talk about not drinking too much. Do you specifically want one that say explicitly an alcoholic should not drink. IMHO this is pretty obvious?!

Comment: See: Halachically Speaking, volume 10, Issue 3, Drinking on Purim, p. 5-9 : http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol10Issue3.pdf

Comment: I believe this is expressed if not explicit in the Old testament

Comment: I agree with @Dov. Do we really need a pesak halakha for this?

Comment: I think this question might be slightly improved if it would ask "if one is an alcoholic, may they drink even the smallest amount?". As above, there are many sources that discourage or forbid one from getting drunk, even if they don't have alcohol problems.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Old Testament? You mean Tanakh. Also, where at?

Comment: @ezra ונשמרתם מאד לנפשתיכם and וחי בהם, off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

A Rav once told me that since I would be having someone who was known to me to have alcohol problems at my Pesach table I shouldn't have wine so as not to be a stumbling block for him.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Aharon. Mi Yodeya isn't like other Q&A websites. I suggest you take a look through our [Help Center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help). What Rav told you this? Do you have a source to back your claim? Why should we trust your rabbi, or more accurately, why should we trust your word on it as a random stranger on the internet? You'll come to find we value sources here, a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The chayei adam says that if drinking wine will leads to kalus rosh, then better not get drunk. Getting drunk is definitely a form of kalus rosh.

> היודע בעצמו שיזלזל אז במצוה מן המצות כנט"י וברכה וברהמ"ז או שלא יתפלל מנחה או מעריב או שינהוג קלות ראש מוטב שלא ישתכר וכל מעשיו יהיה לשם שמים

[the quote is taken from here. Sorry, it's in Hebrew](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chayei_Adam%2C_Shabbat_and_Festivals.155.30?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Chayei_Adam,_Vilna,_1844&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

Comment: This doesn't formally address alcoholism...